# having issue with having a pop up dialog for user to key in username

Tags: android, dialog

I would like to create a dialog, which will prompt the user to key in his/her name.
It will capture the username for the first time hat it is used and display the username whenever the user login.

I've done the coding,
But there's an error occurring.
WHen I want to start the application,
there is a force close error.

logcat:

```
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242): android.app.SuperNotCalledException: Activity {com.example.fuellogproject/com.example.fuellogproject.homeActivity} did not call through to super.onCreate()
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2076)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1038)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:805)
01-25 01:03:24.023: E/AndroidRuntime(8242):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

homeactivity.java

```
public class homeActivity extends Activity{
    Button btnLogIn;
    Button btnAbout;
    SharedPreferences sp;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        final SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        String userName = prefs.getString("user_name", null);
        if (userName == null) {
            EditText input = new EditText(this);
            input.setId(1000);         




            AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setView(input).setTitle("Enter your username!")
                    .setPositiveButton("Ok",
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int which) {
                                    EditText theInput = (EditText) ((AlertDialog) dialog)
                                            .findViewById(1000);
                                    String enteredText = theInput.getText()
                                            .toString();
                                    if (!enteredText.equals("")) {
                                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs
                                                .edit();
                                        editor.putString("user_name",
                                                enteredText);
                                        editor.commit();
                                    }
                                }
                            }).create();
            dialog.show();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: is this answer  worked??

Comment: I've yet to try because it can't work

Answer (score 0):

U missed **super.onCreate()**.. in onCreate() method....